# Barplot of numerical categorical data of number of observations ordered numerically in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I have numerical categorical data in a dataframe which I want to bar plot and order  in ascending order by value. I am able to do it in seaborn easily, but cannot figure out how to order it in pandas or matplotlib. Here is the code, as I said, the seaborn plot is ordered correct, but the pandas plot is not.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'category':['blue','green','red','blue','green','red','blue','green','red','violet'],
        'income':[15,1,4,5,3,2.5,3.4,4.4,12,1.6],
})
print(df)
df['income_cat'] = np.ceil(df["income"]/1.5)
df["income_cat"].where(df["income_cat"]<5,5.0,inplace=True)
df['income_cat'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar',sort_columns=True)
sns.catplot(x='income_cat',kind='count',data=df)
plt.show()
```

Also, any other suggestions to make the plot more "meanigful" are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to order the bars by the value of the index. That can be accomplished by using `sort_index()`:

```
df['income_cat'].value_counts().sort_index().plot(kind='bar',sort_columns=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
df['income_cat'].value_counts().sort_index().plot(kind='bar')
```

Result:

[image]

Hope this helps.